# Property "CWidgetFactory.CGridView" not defined

Tags: yii

Here's the call from my main layout:

```
<div id="mainmenu">

        <?php 
                $this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu',array(
            'items'=>array(
                array('label'=>'Home', 'url'=>array('/site/index')),
                array('label'=>'Services', 'url'=>array('/site/page', 'view'=>'services')),
                array('label'=>'About', 'url'=>array('/site/page', 'view'=>'about')),
                array('label'=>'Contact', 'url'=>array('/site/contact')),
                                array('label'=>'User', 'url'=>array('/user/index')),
                array('label'=>'Login', 'url'=>array('/site/login'), 'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
                array('label'=>'Logout ('.Yii::app()->user->name.')', 'url'=>array('/site/logout'), 'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest)
            ),
        )); ?>
    </div>
```

If I simple call `$this->widget` I get:

> CException: Property "CWidgetFactory.CGridView" not defined.

Is this related with the main.php config file ?

```
'widgetFactory'=>array(
        'CGridView'=>array(
          'cssFile'=>'/css/gridview/styles.css',
          'selectableRows'=>0,
          'pager'=>array(
            'cssFile'=>'/css/pager.css',
           ),
                ),

               'CListView'=>array(
                 'cssFile'=>'/css/listview/styles.css',
                 'pager'=>array(
                    'cssFile'=>'/css/pager.css',
                 ),
               )
),
```

Am I missing something ? I got stuck on this error for a while now. Can't find the reason.

Comment: @Pentium10 : Can you please be more specific... I'm following the instructions on this book: Yii Application Development Cookbook (if this is of any use).

Comment: Arrrgghh!!! I believe I've missed widgets array there... grrr... I will give it a try...

Comment: Solved. Thanks @Pentium10 Was more then enough :) Cheers! yeah!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you are missing something. you forgot widgets imbrication.

```
'widgetFactory'=>array(
  'widgets' => array(
    'CGridView'=>array(
      'cssFile'=>'/css/gridview/styles.css',
      'selectableRows'=>0,
      'pager'=>array(
        'cssFile'=>'/css/pager.css',
       ),
            ),

           'CListView'=>array(
             'cssFile'=>'/css/listview/styles.css',
             'pager'=>array(
                'cssFile'=>'/css/pager.css',
             ),
           )
   )
),
```